# Shiny App crashes when a non-exisiting directory is chosen

Tags: r, error-handling, shiny, shinyapps

My shiny App lets the User choose some Patterns (e.g. company Name) which are part of the path Name like:

```
  Dir <- paste(x,"/",input$Company, "/", input$folder,  " Selection_ESG_Files/", sep="")
  
  dtVaR <- read_csv(paste(Dir, input$Candidate, '-VaR.csv', sep = '')) # load VaR.csv
```

However, if I choose an Input which ends up in a path that does not exist the App crashes. I would like to display an error message that a wrong path was selected and that a new one can be re-selected without the App crashing. Is there a potential way with the validate function?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
Dir <- reactive({
  paste0(x, "/", input$Company, "/", input$folder, " Selection_ESG_Files/")
})

dtVaR <- reactive({
  req(Dir())
  File <- paste0(Dir(), input$Candidate, '-VaR.csv')
  if(file.exists(File)){
    return(read.csv(File))
  }else{
    showNotification("Invalid file.")
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you, but this gives me the following error: `Warning: Error in $: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`. I am actually not trying to subset something, right?

Comment: @R_hub I don't think this error comes from this piece of code. My guess is that you do `dtVaR$...` somewhere, instead of `dtVaR()$...`.

Comment: So I have to use dtVar()$ always then? And additionally it throws this error from this piece of code: `Warning in if (file.exists(File)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

Comment: @R_hub That's because one of your inputs (or `x`) returns a `length > 1` vector. Always ask a question with a reproducible example to get an appropriate answer.